# How to update selected row before segue?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I need to pass a variable containing the index of the selected row in one view to the next view.

firstview.swift

```
var selectedRow = 0;

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedRow = indexPath.row + 1
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "viewAssignmentsSegue") {
            let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as! AssignmentsViewController
            print(selectedRow)
            controller.activeCourse = selectedRow
        }
    }
```

My issue is that, when a row is selected, the `selectedRow` variable isn't updated by the `tableView` method before the segue occurs, meaning that the value is essentially always one behind what it should be. How can I delay the prepareForSegue until the variable is updated or how else can I successfully pass the selected row to the next view without delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: Don't implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Just move that functionality into your `prepareForSegue` implementation. That, after all, is what is called first in response to your tapping the cell. Even in `prepareForSegue` you can ask the table view what row is selected.

Another possibility: Implement `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. It happens earlier.

Comment: How would I go about implementing the functionality into `prepareSegue`?

Answer (score 0):

in your prepareForSegue:

```
 controller.activeCourse = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

don't wait for didSelect to be called - react earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on prepareForSegue:

```
        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        controller.activeCourse = path.row
```

or

```
        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
        controller.activeCourse = path.row
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm brand new to Swift and Xcode, so I'm still trying to figure out some of the basics :)