# Bug with passing data from cell to viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to pass a title(String) from a cell to another controller via a segue, and actually it works, but a behaviour is totally wrong.

*main controller*

```
var cellTitlePressed:String?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellTitlePressed = categories[indexPath.row].title
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCategory", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CategoryVC {
        if let title = cellTitlePressed {
            destination.categoryTitle = title
        } else {
            destination.categoryTitle = "Undefined category"
        }
    }
}
```

If I click on a cell('Beer' category for example) I see "Undefined category" title so I guess the condition doesn't work at first time.

*destination controller*

```
private var _categoryTitle: String!

var categoryTitle:String {
    get {
        return _categoryTitle
    }
    set {
        _categoryTitle = newValue
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var categoryTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    categoryTitleLabel.text = categoryTitle
}
```

Then I come back(dismiss) and click on another category('Coffee') and I see the previous title - 'Beer' instead of 'Coffee' and so on. So it always delayed by one step.

Comment: I would suggest you to use break points on viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and check the value of categoryTitle.Try remove the custom setter and the getter

Comment: what is the value of cellTitlePressed in prepareForSegue ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109152/how-to-update-selected-row-before-segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CategoryVC {
        let currentCell = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        if currentCell != nil {
            destination.categoryTitle = categories[currentCell!].title
        } else {
            destination.categoryTitle = "Undefined category"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to pass a title(String) from a cell to another controller via a segue

Fine, but then delete this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellTitlePressed = categories[indexPath.row].title
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCategory", sender: self)
}
```

You're performing the segue twice: once because the segue is triggered in the storyboard, and again because you are triggering it in code. Instead, just let the storyboard trigger it, and set `cellTitlePressed` in `performSegue` along with the rest of your code.

Also, I don't quite see why `cellTitlePressed` needs to be a *property*. Just use it as a local variable to pass the title into the next view controller. So this is all you need:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CategoryVC {
        let cellTitlePressed = categories[indexPath.row].title
        if let title = cellTitlePressed {
            destination.categoryTitle = title
        } else {
            destination.categoryTitle = "Undefined category"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in your other view controller, your use of `_categoryTitle` and `categoryTitle` is odd, since `categoryTitle` does nothing except act as a front-end for `_categoryTitle`. Plus, as long as you *are* doing that, I would suggest using it to update the interface so that the order of events doesn't matter:

```
var categoryTitle:String {
    get {
        return _categoryTitle
    }
    set {
        _categoryTitle = newValue
        if categoryTitleLabel != nil {
            categoryTitleLabel.title = _categoryTitle
        }
    }
}
```

But personally, I would eliminate `_categoryTitle` and use a setter observer for this:

```
var categoryTitle:String = "" {
    didSet {
        if categoryTitleLabel != nil {
            categoryTitleLabel.title = categoryTitle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it as a local variable, but I had some type errors like `cannot assign value of type Any? to String`, etc. I've deleted that line and segue still works, awesome. But prepare method doesn't know about indexPath, so I've added this line `let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)` and have an error 'Any? is not covertible to UITableViewCell'

Comment: `let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)` works fine, but I've got a million other errors, so I think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: That's great but it isn't what you asked about. I didn't test your code to fix any compile errors because you didn't mention any compile errors; you talked about architectural difficulties and that is what my answer is intended to address.

Comment: I talked about bug when passing of value to another controller is delayed by one step, not architectural difficulties. I've deleted `didSelectRowAt ` function and now it's not sending the value at all, because of those errors.

Comment: But the "delayed by one step" is exactly the problem I solved for you. You assumed that things were happening in this order: `didSelectRowAt`, `prepare(for:)`. You were wrong, for the reason I gave. That was why you were always "one behind". I told you how to straighten things out.

Comment: In fact, your "one behind" issue makes this an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109152/how-to-update-selected-row-before-segue And the solution is the same.